# Resolve Maven dependencies and plugins via GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is there any plugin to resolve the dependencies and plugins via GUI with auto completion?

Like the eclipse marketplace .. Search Maven repository with tomcat .. it will list the related plugins and dependencies and click what you want to install into your POM.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you exactly want?

Comment: Do you mean _resolve_ (which basically means download the artifacts not in your local repo), or do you mean _lookup_ in the "Add Maven Dependency" dialog. If the former, I don't see how it would relate to auto-completion. If the latter, you need to to make sure you have indexing enabled for maven artifacts, then re-index the repo in your workspace (if it already hasn't been indexed). If it hasn't been indexed yet, auto-completion will turn up nothing, as nothing has been indexed

Comment: Do you already have the Maven Plugin for Eclipse? If you do, just right click on the project -> Maven -> Add Dependency. It will bring up the dialog. If you don't then get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m2e plugin (which is included in Eclipse since at least Kepler; for other versions go to the Eclipse Marketplace) contains a dialog. When you enable the Maven nature for a project, then you should get context menus which read "Add Dependency". You can enter part of a name in a dialog and when you click OK, it will add the dependency to the POM.

When indexing is enabled, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> in the POM to get code completion inside of `<dependency>` elements.